# At end of each month automatically replace formulae by values

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible in a column to replace automatically formulas by values at the end of the month?

I was thinking of something like this but it is not working in Google Sheets:

```
sub MyProgram()
DimMyRange As Range
set MyRange=Range("A1")
MyRange=MyRange.Value
End Sub
```

Here is [my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vuQxibkqePHoPJ9FlMQK6AXBr0RXn4ZYVz9etXMwoeI/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

As Pnuts has said, that looks very much like VBA for Excel. I don't recognize it as Javascript anyways. Google Sheets uses Javascript for extended functions.

I've had a quick go at your problem and come up with this as a suggested solution.

```
    function formulaToValues(){
var columnWithFormula = 1; /* If Column A is 1, and B is 2, what column has the formulas to be changed into values */

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange(1, columnWithFormula, sheet.getLastRow(),1)
var values = range.getValues();

range.setValues(values);


}
```

You can change the `columnWithFormula`  & `sheet` parts to suit your particular needs.

You can then attach the script to a Monthly timer, by going to resources ---> Current projects triggers in the script editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [Class ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) and [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) documentation. Googles documentation and code hints in the editor will tell you everything you need to know.

This script will run function 'setVal' on the first day of every Month:

```js
//Create a named range that encompasses your the cells you are interested in.
//Run 'createTrigger' from the Script Editor. Do not run anything else.

ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.
  newTrigger("setVal").
  timeBased().
  onMonthDay(1).
  create();
}

function setVal() {
  var range = ss.getRangeByName('NamedRangeContainingFormula');
  var vals = range.getValues();
  range.setValues(vals);
}
```

If you, for some reason actually need to run on the last Day, you will need (1) a function that will get the last Day of the next month, and (2) a trigger that will delete the current 'setVals' trigger and create a new one. Let us know if thats something you actually need.